# Changing default table names in Django

Tags: django

Django follows the standard applicationName_ModelName for its tables. How can I change it so that it creates a table name that I want ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `db_table` meta option. See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/options/#db-table). For example:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        db_table = "mytable_name"
```

Comment: Thank you will give it  a try